# ui.router: Save $state state when leaving and continous when reentering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My question was bad before, so I rewrote everything.

I'm using `ui.router` for navigation by states.

Normal, if you load a new state, the template and the controller are getting refreshed/reloaded. As I have a couple `ng.repeat` and `ng.if` in the template this causes a flickering, because first the view will render with empty variables and after the controller fetched its data again it will be rendered again.

My idea would be, that I kind of define a interface method  (e.g. 'reactivated') for every state main controller. This method I would call from my navigation menu, where I also set the states.
This actually works quite well.

```
var controllerScope = angular.element($('#content')).scope();
controllerScope.reactivated();
```

My question is: How can I keep the state of a `$state` (rendered html,controller state) while switching to another one, and if reentered continue there where I left?

Answer (score 0):

or You can prevent a state change if user has clicked on the active link

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
          event.preventDefault(); 
          // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
          // a 'transition prevented' error
 })
```